# Can I install linux kernel via apt into different directory?

Tags: kernel, boot, dual-boot

I have an SSD with 4 partitions (EFI partition, 1st user's OS, 2nd user's OS, swap partition) and `systemd-boot` installed as bootloader (personal preference). Since `systemd-boot` can only boot kernel from the same filesystem, I changed `/etc/fstab` to mount my FAT32 partition to `/boot` instead of `/boot/efi`, so that package manager will install kernel on the same partition where `systemd-boot` is located. I have many similar files on that partition (several vmlinuz, but different versions, same with other files), like this:

`ls -> EFI/ loader/ vmlinuz-1 vmlinuz-2 config-1 config-2 ...`

So I separated them into different folders, now it looks like this:
`ls -> EFI/ loader/ user1/ user2/`

The only problem is that when `apt` tries to upgrade system, it fails miserably because it can't symlink files since they are on the FAT32 partition and even if they were able to symlink, they would still be in the main `/boot` folder, which I don't want them to be. Using same kernel is not an option.

So my question is: Is it possible to specify where to download new kernel file is, or I would have to move it manually every time kernel gets an update?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following this article: https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-update-hooks.html

I created `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-efi` script which simply moves compiled kernel and init to user's directory.

```
USER_NAME="mint"
mv "/boot/vmlinuz-$1" "/boot/$USER_NAME/vmlinuz-linux"
mv "/boot/initrd.img-$1" "/boot/$USER_NAME/initramfs-linux.img"
```